# Confused as to which data needs to be passed to login (using requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

I have taken a look at the login data on the forum i'm trying to login too, but it still leaves me confused as to what information is needed to pass along through POST. Is it the html id fields? name fields? type?

Also, when you successfully log on, it has a "Login Successful!" quick redirection page, then continues to redirect you to index.php. The result i'm getting is that of index.php, but it's not an instance of me logged in. I believe i'm passing the cookies through correctly? I just believe it's a matter of wrong 'data' being passed through at login.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import string

headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"}


payload = {"action": "login",
           "username": "myusername",
           "password": "**********"}

with requests.Session() as s:

    s0 = s.post("http://minewind.com/forums/ucp.php?mode=login", data=payload, headers=headers)
    print (s.cookies)

    s1 = s.get("http://minewind.com/forums/index.php", cookies=s0.cookies, headers=headers)

    perty = BeautifulSoup(s1.content)
    perty.prettify()


    for links in perty.find_all('a'):
        print (links.get('href'))
```

Comment: If you look at the page, the login boxes should be part of a `form` whose `action` will contain a URL, which may have various query string parameters. You'll need to use that URL. It should also have a number of `input` fields—one for each box, plus maybe some `hidden` ones. You'll need to send appropriate values for all of them as part of the POST data. If you leave any of that off, you'll probably get rejected and asked to login again.

Comment: so if this was the actual form, which it is: `<form action="./ucp.php?mode=login" method="post" id="login">` then the action will be the url to which i send POST data? Also, the name='' field is what is being used in my POST data, correct? For example: `<input type="text" tabindex="1" name="username" id="username" size="25" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" />`

Comment: Yes on both counts. If that's the actual form, and there are only two `input` fields that look like that and similar with `password` and `action`, then you're doing it right. But is all of that true? Another way to get this information is to use Firebug, Safari or Chrome's built-in debugger, etc. to see the exact request made by your browser when you successfully log in. You can see the URL, the headers, the form data, etc. and make sure your code sends the exact same thing.

Comment: No there were more input fields, you helped me, but i'll have to tinker with it and check it out more, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Note: You can use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to examine the request.

Comment: @Himal: That's another option… but really, the built-in or debuggers in every browser but IE nowadays are usually more than good enough for simple stuff like this.